# Redis multiple connections and multiple incr calls without losing data

Tags: laravel, redis, connection, laravel-5

So I have Laravel 5.2 project where Redis is used as cache driver.

There is a controller, which has method that connects Redis and increases a value and adds value to the set each time this method is called, just like

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->incr($value);
$redis->sadd("set", $value);
```

But the problem is that sometimes there are many connections and many calls for this method at the same time, and there is a data loss, because if two callers call this method while `$value` is 2, after `incr` it will become 3, but should be 4 (after two `incr`s basically).

I have thought about using Redis transactions, but I can't imagine when should I call `multi` command to start a queue and when to `exec` it.

Also I had an idea to collect all `incr`s and `sadd`s as strings to another set and then transact them with `cron job`, but it would cost too much RAM.

So, any suggestions, how can this data loss be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis/) as a Redis driver.

To execute a transaction with Predis you have to invoke the transaction method of the driver and give it a callback:

```
$responses = $redis->transaction(function ($tx) {
  $redis->incr($value);
  $redis->sadd("set", $value);
});
```